# Foundation flexbox grid issue, columns are too big

Tags: html, mobile, zurb-foundation

I've just built a site using the new flex-box option from foundation. It works great EXCEPT when viewed on mobile. For some reason the column stretches to 340px on iphone 5 for example even though the row is 320px. I can add overflow:hidden to the rows but I think that's missing the point

Heres the code

```
<div class="container">
        <!-- HEADER -->
        <header class="row align-middle">
            <div class="columns logo small-12 js-click-effect-again"><i class="fa fa-fighter-jet" aria-hidden="true"></i></i></div>
            <nav class="columns main-nav" role="navigation">
                <ul class="row main-nav-list medium-unstack medium-collapse">
                    <li class="columns"><a href="products.html">Products</a></li>
                    <li class="columns"><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
                    <li class="columns"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                    <li class="columns"><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <main role="main">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="hero-banner columns">
                    <img class="hero-image" src="../DIST/images/banner.jpg">
                    <div class="hero-banner-text">
                        <h1>Qui autem esse poteris, nisi te amor ipse ceperit?</h1>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cur deinde Metrodori liberos commendas? Sed ea mala virtuti magnitudine obruebantur. Sed mehercule pergrata mihi oratio tua. Et ille ridens: Video, inquit, quid agas; Nam Metrodorum non puto ipsum professum, sed, cum appellaretur ab Epicuro, repudiare tantum beneficium noluisse; Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Qui igitur convenit ab alia voluptate dicere naturam proficisci, in alia summum bonum ponere? Nihil ad rem! Ne sit sane; </p>

                        <a class="js-overlay-trigger" href="#">Overlay</a>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="medium-unstack row">
                <div class="columns tile">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150/3B0D0B/fff">
                    <h2 class="tile-title">
                    Some title copy
                    </h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ita prorsus, inquam; Minime vero istorum quidem, inquit. Qualem igitur hominem natura inchoavit? Duo Reges: constructio interrete. </p>
                    <a class="button" href="">A link</a>
                </div>
                <div class="columns tile">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150/E8C0A8/fff">
                    <h2 class="tile-title">
                    Some title copy
                    </h2>
                    <p>Nihil illinc huc pervenit. Eam stabilem appellas. Bonum patria: miserum exilium. Quae diligentissime contra Aristonem dicuntur a Chryippo. Occultum facinus esse potuerit, gaudebit; Confecta res esset. </p>
                    <a class="button" href="">A link</a>
                </div>
                <div class="columns tile">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/320x150/63649E/fff">
                    <h2 class="tile-title">
                    Some title copy
                    </h2>
                    <p>Hoc loco tenere se Triarius non potuit. Igitur ne dolorem quidem. At iam decimum annum in spelunca iacet. Dat enim intervalla et relaxat. Respondeat totidem verbis. Atqui reperies, inquit, in hoc quidem pertinacem; </p>
                    <a class="button" href="">A link</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="text-block row">
                <div class="columns">
                    <div class="text-block-content">
                        <h3>Verba tu fingas et ea dicas, quae non sentias?</h3>

                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. An ea, quae per vinitorem antea consequebatur, per se ipsa curabit? Si alia sentit, inquam, alia loquitur, numquam intellegam quid sentiat</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </main>


        <footer class="main-footer row">
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="columns">
                        <div class="footer-group accordion js-accordion">
                            <h4 class="footer-group-title accordion-trigger js-accordion-trigger">Group title<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h4>
                            <ul class="footer-list accordion-content js-accordion-content">
                                <li><a href="#">A footer link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">A footer link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">A footer link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">A footer link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="columns">
                        <div class="footer-group accordion js-accordion">
                            <h4 class="footer-group-title accordion-trigger js-accordion-trigger">Group title<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h4>
                            <ul class="footer-list accordion-content js-accordion-content">
                                <li><a href="#">A footer link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">A footer link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">A footer link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">A footer link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="columns">
                        <div class="footer-group accordion js-accordion">
                            <h4 class="footer-group-title accordion-trigger js-accordion-trigger">Group title<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h4>
                            <ul class="footer-list accordion-content js-accordion-content">
                                <li><a href="#">A footer link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">A footer link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">A footer link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">A footer link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="columns">
                        <div class="footer-group accordion js-accordion">
                            <h4 class="footer-group-title accordion-trigger js-accordion-trigger">Group title<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></h4>
                            <ul class="footer-list accordion-content js-accordion-content">
                                <li><a href="#">A footer link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">A footer link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">A footer link</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">A footer link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="columns copyright align-bottom">&copy;2016</span>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

I'm using the default foundation and haven't added anything to override it so I can't figure out what's going on? Am I missing something

Answer (score 0):

Not seeing anything "wrong" here but I don't have the CSS. I set up a demo that you can add your CSS to, fork it, post back the link http://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/RojaGW

btw: you don't need this 2nd set of columns

```
 <nav class="columns main-nav" role="navigation">
```